# countable direct sum of cyclic abelian $p^{2}$ groups

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, abelian-groups, noncommutative-rings

Let $G={{\Bbb{Z}}_{p^{2}}}^{(\aleph)}$ (countable direct sum of copies of ${\Bbb{Z}}_{p^2}$). It is clear that every subgroup of $G$ is a  homomorphic image of $G$. Now this is my question:

Is it true that every factor of $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$? (e.q., for every $H\leq G$,
$G/H\hookrightarrow G$)

Comment: Yes, every abelian group of finite exponent is a direct sum of cyclic groups. (A more general result is cited p1 of https://www.jstor.org/stable/2040744)

Comment: Thank you very much dear. I found the theorem in kaplansky's book that says:    Let G be a countable p-group with no element of infinite height. then G is a direct sum of cyclic groups.

Comment: Thank you very much dear. I found the theorem in kaplansky's book that says:    If  G is  a countable p-group with no element of infinite height,  then G is a direct sum of cyclic groups.       Is this Theorem true for non-countable case. In fact,  I need to prove that : 
 If of $G=\oplus_{\Lambda}{\Bbb{Z}}_{p^{n}}$ where $\Lambda$ is a set (not necessarily countable), then $G/H$ is a direct sum of cyclic abelian groups for every $H\Leq G$.

Comment: I provided a reference: the result I'm mentioning is true in the uncountable case.